# Meaningful question titles

Tags: discussion, questions, titles

I visited Code Review the first time and noticed that many question titles are meaningless. For example I found the following titles on the front page.

- How can I make this program a bit more efficient?
- Is this code thread safe?
- Can this code be minified even more?
- Potential Problems with this templating technique

Since this site is about make code more efficient and behaving better, there is a high potential for question titles to just repeat what this site is about. By the way, in the above titles, the use of the word "this" is what removes the meaning of those questions.

Have anyone noticed that and consider it an issue? Should we warn questioners if their title contains the word "this"?

Comment: You're right! We should edit those titles when stumbling upon them. I tried to do this recently, but I'm feeling alone. :) Feel free to suggest edits to make the question better.

Comment: There is more :) http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title