# Prompt for more meaningful question titles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, titles

I'd like to make a feature request to elicit more [meaningful question titles](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/9357), because I'm tired of editing generic titles.  Right now, when you ask a question, the title field contains the hint

> what's your code review request about? Be specific.

I propose changing the hint to say:

> State the purpose of your code and mention any major concerns.

… or even better:

> State the purpose of your code and mention any major concerns. Make your title distinctive.

Comment: I fully support this.  I improve titles whenever I can, but sometimes I just cannot tell what the OP's code is doing (if no info is given).  This site especially needs good titles, otherwise we'll lose traffic.

Comment: One week after I proposed this, there are four upvotes, one favourite, and no dissent. Does anyone know how we would go about making it happen?

Comment: it sounds like this question has been asked before with different wording ([Improved title filter](https://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/435/18427)) and that post links other places as well.

Comment: This is not something easily configurable by site moderators but has to go through Stack Exchange, so there needs to be more discussion concerning the wording as well as whether it will actually make a meaningful difference. **In the meantime, please edit bad titles wherever you see them.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just made this change, actually a bit surprised that it took *this* long to be noticed. Sorry about the delay in our response, this is now live.