# What would Clippy say?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, low-quality-posts

We have a [question closure rate of ~30%](/a/5421/9357).  That's a significant burden on moderators and users who help triage the questions.

While some questions can indeed be very difficult to triage, there are also many many incoming questions that are obviously bad just from a split-second glance.  [Stack Exchange already has heuristics that can tell whether a question is likely to be low-quality](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26848135#26848135).  Wouldn't it be nice if we could automatically prevent some of the obviously problematic questions from being submitted in the first place?

It is probably a bad idea to ban certain phrases outright.  However, we could certainly display some *warnings* while the user is typing in a question.

### What if we had…

```html
a Clippy?                                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/clippy.js/1.0/clippy.min.css"><style type="text/css">body { color: transparent; } .clippy, .clippy-balloon { position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 150px; }</style><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/clippy.js/1.0/clippy.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">clippy.load('Clippy', function(agent) { agent.show(); agent.play('CheckingSomething'); agent.speak("It looks like you are writing a question that might not be appropriate on Code Review"); agent.play('Explain'); agent.speak("because your question contains (fill in the reason)."); agent.play('GetAttention');  agent.speak("Please consult the Help Center before posting."); });</script>
```

What phrases would trigger Clippy's activation, and what would he say?

Please post your suggestions below, one trigger (or one set of very closely related triggers) per answer.  Include justifications for why you believe the trigger has predictive power.

### In seriousness…

A real Clippy would be rather annoying.  In reality, I'm talking more about pop-up tips like this:

[image: "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed"]

Comment: From a technical perspective: is such a feature supported by the SE devs or would we be the first site to ask for such?

Comment: @Mast [Shog9 encouraged this feature request.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4456715#4456715) I assume that it is realistically feasible.

Comment: see also [Ways to give users some specific education about question quality and topicality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277607/165773) at MSE

Comment: @Mast: Such a thing [is already present on SO at least](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290740/provide-asking-instructions-for-regex-just-like-for-sql).

Comment: Question: why not follow your own comment with click-through warning? Wouldn't it suffice? http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5416/what-would-you-say-is-the-biggest-problem-code-review-is-facing-as-a-site-as-of/5421#comment12376_5421

Comment: This post has been [mentioned on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285919/148099).

Answer (score 44):

### No code in the question

Very easy to test for. If there is not a single formatted full line of code in a question:

> Code Review questions **must** include the code to be reviewed **in the body of the question**.

Comment: This is more of a hard error when clicking submit than a Clippy message while typing, but I'll take it.

Comment: Maybe a warning if somebody embeds a link to github/pastebin/(other common code hosting service)?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting a link to your project IMO. Say you post a class for review, it could be helpful to provide a github link as a compliment.

Comment: Linking to a repository is just a potential warning sign. Something along the lines of "Please make sure that you have included the code you want reviewed in the question".

Comment: @Kaz I for one always include all the relevant code in the question *and* link to Git because if there are dependencies as submodules, people'd rather clone

Comment: Ok, done: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/code-review-questions-must-contain-code

Answer (score 28):

#### Machine Learning

There's way too many cases to consider here, we should apply Machine Learning to this to make a machine learn what makes a question likely to be a bad question.

I have recently studied Machine Learning, and to me this sounds like a multi-class classification problem, to which it is possible to apply Logistic Regression, and/or Neural Networks.

No, I am not kidding.

Yes, I think this is feasible.

Why do I think this has predictive power? Well, that's the whole point of Machine Learning.

Comment: I like this suggestion much better than trying to guess some poor heuristics by hand. That said, since it would be a major undertaking to implement, it won't happen from alone.

Comment: Can a community implement this by themselves? Shouldn't this rather be posted as a feature request on the general SE meta? I can see this being useful on all communities.

Comment: I had considered piping everything to SpamAssassin and training it.

Comment: @jacwah  The rules are going to be very different on each community though.  For example, here a question mark is a sign of a bad title.  On other sites, its lack would be.  Also, there are a lot of advantages to trying to do this in a small way initially rather than a big way.  I would hate to be stuck with code that did not work for this site but which would be a low priority to fix since it worked everywhere else.

Comment: @mdfst13 I wasnt refering to this question as a whole but this answer in particular. Implementing a machine learning algorithm would be a general solution applicable to all communities. It could just be run as a separate instance for each one.

Comment: @jacwah In response to "Can a community implement this..." I agree; this could potentially be helpful across all of SE. However, I fear that if we put this on the general SE meta, it will take 6 - 8 weeks before they start working on it. I'd say it'd be fine in the mean time if we tried implementing this ourselves.

Comment: Would Duga take control of this, and perhaps print her findings to the 2nd?

Comment: @SirPython That makes sense.

Comment: @jacwah Any developer who is familiar with Machine Learning can implement this by themselves.

Comment: Just use this: http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/ JS neural network

Comment: @CrazyPython The neural network library is not the hard part, deciding on the features, gathering data and analyzing results is a harder part of Machine Learning.

Comment: Ping me when you start the project. I'll be happy to contribute.

Comment: Well, this is one of the most massive programming communities on SE. I think we have the right dev community to give it a try at least :)

Comment: If this takes off, we could potentially also use it at [physics.SE]. Of course the rules would be different, but we get a lot of questions that seem amenable to formulaic improvements or suggestions for improvement. I'd love to be kept in the loop about any progress.

Comment: Questions on SE are closed for various reasons. Training a ML model that can handle all cases for all different sites together is going to be hard. Tackling specific scenarios and building it up from there seems a good way to start. As @SimonForsberg said, anyone can use a ML library and just look at how to use its API. It's however important to select the correct features that match the scenario. E.g. One of the features could be the presence of code or absence, or the length of code snippets. Still machine learning is no silver bullet, there will be false positives.

Comment: @DJanssens And there will likely be false negatives. I think the only reasonable way is to do it at one site first, then see how that goes, then see if it is worth implementing on other sites.

Comment: I agree @SimonForsberg. I don't see SE itself implement a thing like Clippy (based on ML) anytime soon. But I do believe that the community can steer them in that direction if the results are trustworthy and good.

Comment: We use something like this on Stack Overflow. It's slightly accurate on a good day, and requires a lot of handholding to be useful. But if you're motivated to try doing something for CR, download the data-dump and give it a shot...

Comment: @Shog9 "something like this" = actual machine learning? Is this something anything open source, or is this something only developed and distributed internally on Stack Exchange?

Comment: [What I'm referring to](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267778/details-of-the-quality-score-algorithm-as-discussed-in-the-recent-podcast), @Simon.

Answer (score 25):

### Title contains "this * code" or "do* this"

**Every single question** with ["this code" or "this *[language]* code"](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461928/quality-control-for-questions-whose-title-matches-a-pattern?TitlePatterns=%25this%25%20code%25) in the title has been retitled, closed, and/or downvoted; some have comments asking for clarification.

The same goes for ["do this" or "doing this"](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461928/quality-control-for-questions-whose-title-matches-a-pattern?TitlePatterns=%25do%25%20this%25).  (The wildcard used for the Data Explorer query is crude and catches more titles than a properly crafter regular expression would, but the results are still surprisingly predictive.)

Clippy could say

> "This code" is too generic.  Please tell us *what* your code does — see [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for examples of acceptable titles.

Comment: Very useful query.  I can't say I'm surprised by the number of bad titles, but at least this makes it easier to fix them.

Answer (score 22):

### Title that looks like a question

The following patterns in a question title predict a problematic post:

- How …?
- Can …?
- Should …?
- Would …?
- …? (i.e., a title that ends with a question mark)

The tip could say:

> Titles that contain a specific question are generally inappropriate for Code Review.  Please see [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask).

#### Predictive ability

I think that this heuristic works because:

- It suggests that the poster did not heed [Stop mentioning major concerns in title](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2454/9357).
- It may indicate that the poster wants a specific question answered rather than an open-ended review, making the question off-topic.
- In the more benign cases, the post can be improved simply by [stripping off noise words](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/148099) like "How to …?" in the title.
- In the worse cases, the title fails to provide any hint at all as to what the purpose of the code is.  Then we need to [pester the poster](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4957/9357) to rewrite the title.

[This Data Explorer query](//data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461928/quality-control-for-questions-whose-title-matches-a-pattern?TitlePatterns=How+%25%7CCan+%25%7CShould+%25%7CWould+%25%7C%25%3F) shows that most of these questions get closed or need their title to be edited.  (Recent data is more indicative, since off-topic questions eventually get [automatically deleted](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/148099) and [no longer show up in Data Explorer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/157462/148099).)

Of course, this filter also has some false positives, such as:

- [How to speak Brainfuck: for beginners](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97628)
- [Are your servers down...?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113676)
- [Simon Says: is this too complex?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114181)
- [Is it Friday yet?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67636)
- [Beheading of knights, who survives?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104645)
- [Excuse me, how many of you are new here? Mind if I JOIN you?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97890)
- [Simon, Mat's Mug, what's the (rating) difference?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114328)

Comment: ... so you hit the "ask question" button, but if you then have a question mark then it's a bad question? Your data point might be valid, but there's something else wrong about it - maybe on CR we aren't looking for questions ... but rephrasing that is something that would be pretty hard for SE to do, I think.

Answer (score 18):

### Title or body contains the word "wrong" or "incorrect"

These words almost always indicate that the code is broken.

The tip could say:

> Please note that questions containing code that produces incorrect results are [off-topic](/help/on-topic) for Code Review.

#### Predictive ability

We get such questions posted [every few hours](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=wrong&Room=8595&User=-263&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest).

However, of the questions with "wrong" or "incorrect" in the title, we only keep [a few per month](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461928/quality-control-for-questions-whose-title-matches-a-pattern?TitlePatterns=%25wrong%25%7C%25incorrect%25), so quickly are they closed and deleted.  The ones we keep are mostly "Anything wrong with my code?" questions, which deserve a better title anyway.

Examples of false positives:

- [Add transactional Units of Work to incorrect NHibernate usage (microsessions, single object actions)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123423)
- ["Researcher Hatim is right or wrong" challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119299)
- [Proof that I was wrong about Random Number Generators](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64430)

The presence of ["wrong"](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461933/quality-control-for-questions-with-certain-phrases-in-the-body?BodySearchString=wrong) in the body appears to be somewhat predictive as well.  On the other hand ["incorrect"](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461933/quality-control-for-questions-with-certain-phrases-in-the-body?BodySearchString=incorrect) appearing in the body seems to be fine — they are often string literals that appear in validation code.

Comment: Further keywords might include "Stacktrace", "Error", "Fix", but those may have too many false-positives

Comment: Don't forget "Segfault" and the likes. False positives aren't as problematic when warning IMO.

Comment: This could potentially trigger a lot of false positives.  Some questions describe a (supposedly) clean way they had originally tried, but it didn't work, so they figured it out, and want help cleaning up their code.

Comment: for this kind of questions it would help to have stats on how many of their askers simply try to circumvent question block at SO ([here is example stats request at Progs meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6592/31260) just in case if you don't have these). Thing is, for this kind of askers heuristics and Clippy message [could probably be different](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260 "example") - that is, in case if stats show that there are many of them

Comment: @gnat I'm not confident enough to block anything at this point. The goal is purely advisory, and therefore circumvention is not a concern. The crappiest posters gonna post crap.

Comment: I'm not talking about block, only better targeted warning "Wait... Note that Stack Overflow topics are not covered here and that your questions can't even be migrated to Stack Overflow because of the block." But even this is moot since without stats there is no way to tell whether it's worth it, what I really recommend is to request stats and act based on these

Comment: ...(on a further thinking) I would go as far as to say that blocking askers only by the fact of block at SO would be really bad idea. Their inability to properly ask SO kind questions can't reliably indicate inability to ask CR kind ones - sites just differ too much for that. All these folks need is indeed a fair warning that SO kind troubleshooting is off-topic at CR and that their questions can't migrate to SO because of the block

Answer (score 18):

### Body contains only code, or only a few, short, non-code parts

This could indicate that the user is not explaining what their code doing and it, more or less, providing a code dump.

The message could say something along these lines:

> Be sure to add information to your post describing what your code is doing.

Comment: off my head: [code that does something] // this does XYZ, but slowly, how to improve? :-)

Answer (score 12):

### "me" or "my" in the title

[A vast majority](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461928/quality-control-for-questions-whose-title-matches-a-pattern?TitlePatterns=%25%20me%20%25%7C%25%20my%20%25) of questions with "me" or "my" in the title need rework.  They are not necessarily bad questions, just poor titles.

The advice might say (I'm not very sure about how to phrase it):

> Please ensure that the title is about the purpose of the code, rather than about you.  See [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for examples of acceptable titles.

Comment: Seems this one should be combined with the "this * code" filter.

Answer (score 8):

### "better" or "improve" (or "improvement") in the title

[Nearly every question](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461928/quality-control-for-questions-whose-title-matches-a-pattern?TitlePatterns=%25%20better%20%25%7C%25%20improve%25) can drop these words from the title, especially if it's not a [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) question.

Granted, these titles tend to not be as vague as the "this code" questions.  Still, showing a warning would help prevent the pushback that occasionally occurs when someone edits the title later.

Clippy could say:

> Please ensure that the title states what your code does.  Seeking improvement on all aspects of the code is implied for Code Review questions, so specific concerns need not be mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 6):

### Code that should be in a code block

We get lots of questions with malformed code blocks from users who are unfamiliar with how to create code blocks in Markdown by indenting everything by four spaces.  Ideally, Stack Exchange should [Implement ```-style (fenced) Markdown code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/148099), but until then, we are going to get posts that look like this:

public class HelloWorld {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
```

}

Clippy can provide advice:

> To post your code, paste it into the editor, select the entire code block, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

Some patterns that would indicate malformed code blocks:

- A line that ends in `{` or `}` but doesn't start with 4 spaces:

  ```
  ^(?! {4}).*[{}]$
  ```
- A line that starts with the word `def`:

  ```
  ^def\s
  ```
- A line that starts with the word `class` or `module`:

  ```
  ^class\s
  ^module\s
  ```

So as not to be too annoying, the check should happen maybe five seconds after the suspicious line is typed, or when the <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd> button is clicked.

Comment: Would that regex have to parse the HTML source inside the preview? If so, we could perhaps just look for a curly brace anywhere between `<p></p>` tags (see the HTML source for your malformed code block)

Comment: @Phrancis Good question. I don't know whether Clippy would receive the Markdown or the rendered HTML. I've assumed Markdown here.

Comment: Okay, I'm thinking of @Duga for reference, she uses the HTML to parse the edits for answer invalidation, if any edited text is between <code> tags, not sure if Clippy would use the same method though, guess that would be more of an implementation detail though.

Answer (score 5):

### Title contains "refactor…", "avoid", "improv…", "too many", or "DRY", or title starts with "need"

[These titles](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461928/quality-control-for-questions-whose-title-matches-a-pattern?TitlePatterns=Need%20%25%7Cneed%20%25%7C%25%20refactor%25%7C%25%20avoid%20%25%7C%25%20improv%25%7C%25%20too%20many%20%25%7C%25%20dry%20%25) describe a concern about the code.

Clippy could say:

> Please ensure that the title states what your code does, and reviewers will point out what needs to be improved.

Answer (score 5):

### Title contains "shorter", "shorten", "optimi…", "efficien…"

[These titles](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461928/quality-control-for-questions-whose-title-matches-a-pattern?TitlePatterns=%25%20shorten%20%25%7C%25%20shortening%20%25%7C%25%20shorter%20%25%7C%25%20optimi%25%7C%25%20efficien%20%25) describe a concern about the code.

Clippy could say:

> Efficiency and optimization are implied for every question on Code Review.  The title should simply state the task accomplished by the code.

Answer (score 4):

### "statements", "loops", "else", or "catch" in the title

[These titles](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/461928/quality-control-for-questions-whose-title-matches-a-pattern?TitlePatterns=%25%20statements%20%25%7C%25%20nested%20%25%7C%25%20loops%20%25%7C%25%20else%20%25%7C%25%20catch%20%25) indicate that the question is likely to be closed as generic example code, or that the title needs to be rewritten.

Clippy could say:

> Please ensure that the title states what your code does. If the code is a purely generic example that has no specific purpose, then the question would be off-topic for Code Review.